# Assign object value with lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

i would like to assign value to object using lambda expression in C#. This is for a MVC control that im working on.

```
@Control.GridView(
settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "gvEditing";
    settings.KeyFieldName = "ProductID";
});
```

I search on google but i did not find any example.

Thank you!

Comment: Step #1: stop using type names for your variable names. Step #2: please be more specific. The code you posted doesn't explain at all what you're actually trying to do and "assign value to object using lambda" could mean just about anything. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Its just an example. I would like to use the same syntax pass value to a new object. In this case GridView contains an object settings. And i would like to initialize the GridView object and assign value to attribute settings with this syntax.

Comment: I understand it's _meant_ to be an example. But it's not an example of anything in a way that helps explain your question. Please consult the references I mentioned and edit your post, if you would like for anyone to understand what you're asking and provide a good answer.